# Proving a calculus of variatons inequality:

Tags: calculus, integration, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to prove that if

$$\int_\Omega\frac{|\nabla w|^2}{2} - wf dx$$

Is a functional with a minimizer of $u$ among all possible $w$, then:

$$\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot\nabla(w - u)dx \geq \int_\Omega (w-u)f dx$$

So far I have managed to prove the following:

Assume $u$ is such a minimum, then by definition we get:

$$\int_\Omega \frac{|\nabla w|^2}{2} - wfdx \geq \int_\Omega \frac{|\nabla u|^2}{2} dx - ufdx$$

But then:

$$\int_\Omega \frac{|\nabla w|^2}{2} -\frac{|\nabla u|^2}{2} dx \geq \int_\Omega wf - ufdx$$

Which gives us:

$$\int_\Omega \frac{(\nabla w - \nabla u) \cdot (\nabla w + \nabla u)}{2} dx \geq \int_\Omega wf - ufdx$$

This is so close, but it's missing just the last little bit. I have tried using the triangle inequality or adding positive terms to the lhs to turn it into $\nabla u \nabla(w - u)$. Could someone throw me a hint for that last step?

Comment: Replace $w$ with $u + \epsilon (w - u)$ and drive $\epsilon \to 0$?